# Como Atualizar Tabela do Banco de Dados mysqli com UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Eu estou criando um sistema de listagem de dados, e criei um página de alteração de dados, com 6 campos, nome, experiência, email, telefone, cidade e biografia.
só que minha função não atualiza os campos. Os dados chegam na função **alterar_dados()** mas não atualiza no banco de dados.Somente o campo experiência atualiza.

```
 function Altera_Dados(){
  $retorno="";
  $conecta = DBConnect();

  if(isset($_POST["atualiza"])){        
        $Nome = $_REQUEST['DadoNome']; 
        echo $_REQUEST['DadoNome'];
        $experiencia = $_POST['experiencia'];
        echo $_POST['experiencia'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];  
        echo $_POST['email'];     
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        echo $_POST['telefone'];
        $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
        echo $_POST['cidade'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    //$biografia = $_POST['biografia'];

        $query ="UPDATE cadastro3 SET nome = '$Nome',experiencia='$experiencia',email='$email' where id ='$id'";
        $retorno = mysqli_query($conecta,$query)or die ('Erro na consulta ::. '. mysqli_error($conecta));
     }
  DBClose($conecta);
  return $retorno;
}
```

Utilizei o ID ai a seguinte menssagem aparece:
 mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\Dozero\System\funcoes.php on line 284
Aviso: Não foi atualizado!

Comment: Melhor assim. Este código é extremamente inseguro. Percebo que ninguém valida nada, ninguém se preocupa se está certo, só quer ver funcionando. Aí não adianta consertar um problema. Na verdade se resolver esse problema é pior porque a pessoa vai achar que agora está ok.

Comment: Agora estamos no caminho. há um erro na sua consulta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente pelo *ID*. O problema pode ser no where. Você deve está buscando algo que não exista:

```
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE cadastro3 SET nome ='$Nome',experiencia='$experiencia',email='$email' WHERE id=$id");

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
  echo "Sucesso: Atualizado corretamente!";
}else{
  echo "Aviso: Não foi atualizado!";
}

mysql_close($conexao);
```

Comment: mas para isso ele deve passar o ID como POST também

Comment: Que passe então.

Comment: kkkkkk calma rapaz só comentei para ele não ter problemas

Comment: Desculpas @Victor não quis ser ignorante.

Comment: obrigado estou testando . depois vou implementar segurança, o importante agora é funcionar

Comment: Consegiu @HamiltonVentura ?

Comment: sim consegui está atualizando todos os campos certinho, acho que era a "id" mesmo. mas essa mensagem fica aparecendo: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ConstrutoresFree\Dozero\System\funcoes.php on line 290
Aviso: Não foi atualizado!